# Computational Geometry Algorithm

Tags: geometry, algorithms, recursion, computational-mathematics

> Show that there exists a line passing through one red point and one blue point such that the number of red points on one side of the line is equal to the number of blue points on the same side. Describe how to find such a line in $O(n\log n)$ time.

note:  There are n red points and n blue points on the plane and no three
points are collinear.

For this problem I don't know where to start. I know how to find the shortest distance between a pair of points in $n \log n$ time but for this problem is it like a similar algorithm? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There can be anywhere in the 2d space.It is an algorithm should work for any number of points.

Comment: I don't think it is always possible (for example if you have a triangle of blue points with a red point in its centre). Should there be an equal number of red and blue points? And is that number $n$?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to declare the assumption in the beginning of the problem, I edit the question now accordingly